# How to automatically add ',' to numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

So that 335000 become 335,000?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) function :

```
$number = 335000;
echo number_format($number);
```

Will get you :

```
335,000
```

And, if necessary, you can use the additionnal parameters *(see the manual page)* to use a different number of digits, another decimal separator, ...